# Query with boolean atribute too long on CosmosDB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

CosmosDB is wonderful, at the beginning, later is very difficult to adjust performance, since it not a really MongoDB.

My collection has almost 3 millions of records. Each record has between 15 to 21 fields.

I have a process do control, so I put some boolean attributes to check if the process was queued, processed, etc. Thinking that could be easy for database manipulate.

But, I can't explain, literally, because the explain() command from MongoDB, applied to CosmosDB does not return valuable information, such what indexes were used.

Example, if I try to run a query with a specific field, always I got "Request Too Large". Other fields, boolean, returns quite fast.
When I put the sort based on "_id", the query became a little bit fast fot while, then start to take long.

If I adjust the Throughput runs fine, but the costs start to rise a lot.

I was wondering if could be better, instead 3 ou 4 fields boolean, replace them to one field text, and let the index do the job.

Mayabe am I missing something here?

Recap: CosmosDB has a structure which index all fields, except the booleans, as the MongoDB.

Comment: I'm using Python 3 and Pymongo to access.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that switching to a single properly indexed field would solve your performance problem (assuming value is selective enough). To get conclusive answers, please provide [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with sample document, indexing policy and example query.

Comment: Yes, @ImrePühvel, I try that and works much better. Now time to change all my database. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the column to have more variance, the indexes can work properly, even with low Read Units.

I think boolean values should not be used as filter columns is big databases, they don't vary much, and requires almost long table scan actions.